# Is there any danger to giving out a check routing number for a purchase?

Tags: banking

Is there any danger to giving out a check routing number for a purchase? I gave out a routing number and now concerned that it could be used to draw out more then I authorized.

Comment: The routing number identifies the *bank* and possibly *account type*, not the customer. That number is public anyway. You mean the account number?

Answer (score 10):

Not really any more dangerous than giving out a physical check *with the exact same information* printed on it.
You'll notice signs in many stores which tell you in one way or another that if you give them a check they're going to process it electronically - which ends up being the same as if you're just giving them the routing numbers off the check.